# Entry value updated in VM but not in UI - Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mvvm, xamarin.forms

In my VM I am assigning value to CurrentItem.SecondValue when Toggle is checked it gets whatever value is entered in FirstValue Entry, but value is not getting updated in UI unless I refresh it/navigate between pages. When I debug it I see that CurrentItem.SecondValue is updated in VM. Any suggestions how it can be fixed?
XAML:

```
<renderer:CustomKeyEntry x:Name="FirstValue" Text="{Binding CurrentItem.FirstValue}" HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="250" BackgroundColor="#FFFFFF"  Margin="15, 0" TextColor="Black" IsEnabled="{Binding IsThisEnabled}" ReturnType="Next" />  

<common:Toggle Text="{i18n:Translate Use_This_Number}" Checked="{Binding SecondValueIsFirstValue}" TextColor="Gray" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" IsEnabled="{Binding IsThisEnabled}" Margin="0,0,10,0" />  

<renderer:CustomKeyEntry x:Name="SecondValue" Text="{Binding CurrentItem.SecondValue}" HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="250" BackgroundColor="#FFFFFF"  Margin="15, 0" TextColor="Black" ReturnType="Next"/>
```

ViewModel:

```
private Boolean _secondValueIsFirstValue= false;

    public Boolean SecondValueIsFirstValue
    {
        get { return _secondValueIsFirstValue; }
        set
        {                
            if (_secondValueIsFirstValue!= value)
            {
                if (value)
                {
                    CurrentItem.SecondValue = CurrentItem.FirstValue;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }                       
              SetProperty(ref _secondValueIsFirstValue, value);                                     
            }               
        }
    }

private ItemDTO _currentItem;
public ItemDTO CurrentItem
        {
            get { return _currentItem;}
            set { SetProperty(ref _currentItem, value); }
        }

 //DTO Class
 public class ItemDTO : INotifyPropertyChanged    
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;                     
        ....
    }
```

Comment: we can't help debug code that we can't see.  Please post the relevant code

Comment: @Jason I just want to know what is a proper way of doing it. Added my code.

Comment: the property name you are passing to RaisePropertyChanged does not appear to match the name of the property you are binding to

Comment: @Jason typo, sorry

Comment: Not understanding not happening in real time.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT my label was updating while user was typing value to the entry, but now I need to refresh page( or navigate between pages) in order to see it.

Comment: @Ika Okey, Label need to bind Entry's Text as follow.`<Label BindingContext="{x:Reference MyEntry}" Text="{Binding Path=Text}".../>  <Entry x:Name="MyEntry" />`

Comment: @Ika Sorry not found taht logic using ViewModel. You can upload a sample project, I will check it.

Comment: Have you debug your code ? What is attached to Item_PropertyChanged handler and are you sure it goes in ? Cause if it does update when navigating back, I think that might be a prob of raise property changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to update Fody NuGet package.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't sure if you wanted the exact code or guidance - if you want the exact code for a fairly simple problem that requires extensive writing, this is not a site where someone else will write your code and the question should be closed.

So assuming you want the guidance what you basically need to do is to have TwoWay Binding for the entries. When they are changed it will activate the setters in your ViewModel. There you need to activate calculation of the new total and then use raise PropertyChanged to refresh the value.

If you haven't understood anything of the above, you need to spend some time reading about MVVM before asking further questions.

Comment: I tried two way binding it still does not work. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: As far as I can tell from the other answer you have tried that on the label which is nonsense (does nothing), it should be implemented on the entry. But still that won't do anything either, it is just one step. Only doing EVERYTHING mentioned above will work, partial implementation won't help in any way.

Answer (score -1):

Here is something that might help you, you can bind the labels in yaml, there are different modes like : OneWay, TwoWay, ... you can find more about the bindings on this url : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/binding-mode

This is the start of an answer for the label :

```
{Binding CurrentItem.Amount,Mode=TwoWay}
```

I hope this helps you

Have a nice day